# Chrome says my website contains malware?

Tags: google-chrome, malware-detection

Chrome saying while I am accessing my site, after searching I cleaned my code from the site but chrome still showing then I removed all files from my site and just upload index.html (blank file) but warning is still showing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chrome warnings will be based on black-lists which record where malware has been found in a site or domain, this isn't a live "scan" and does not necessarily mean that malware is on *that* page or at that specific *time*. It is not clear from your question if you've created a new folder and index.html and you are also seeing a malware warning when browsing to that URL, or if you've replaced your site content with an empty folder and index.html and that warning is still showing. Once you have taken the steps to disinfect the site then you can request a review which should help remove the warning http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=163633.

The malware warning should be taken seriously even if you are confident in your own site content as crackers use automatic toolkits to find vulnerabilities in websites and inject code into them to infect visitors, as these kits are largely automatic there isn't the protection in obscurity you might otherwise assume.

If you've not been able to find and fix the issue Chrome is warning about, you owe it to your visitors- and your own reputation- to take the site content down until you can resolve the problem.

Comment: Yes I removed all files from my site & just upload index.html (blank file) but warning is still showing

Comment: As I say this will be due to your site being on a list of infected sites detected by Google or another party (the list is maintained by http://www.stopbadware.org/). The warning should eventually disappear but this will not happen in real time, if you have cleaned up your site (it's not possible to advise on this without more information on the site) then you can request a review which should lead to your site being removed from the list (see http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168328&topic=2365140&ctx=topic) but this may take a day or two.

Comment: The advise at http://www.stopbadware.org/common-hacks might help as a starting point.

Answer (score 8):

Google Chrome's malware blacklists should be based on same data used by Google's safebrowsing advisory.  You can access this information for a particular site (e.g. *stackoverflow.com*) via the following url:

`http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=stackoverflow.com`

Just replace the domain with your own and it should give you some indication why your site generated malware warnings in Chrome.

Comment: I did it and the result stated that no unsafe content found. My free hosting website is from this provider: https://www.000webhost.com/cpanel-login. May I know why Google is still marking my site as unsafe? There is a big red screen stating that 'Deceptive site ahead' although my site is totally safe

Answer (score -3):

1.In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu Chrome menu.
Select Settings.
Click Show advanced settings.
Under "Privacy," uncheck the box "Protect you and your device from dangerous sites."

Comment: could you elaborate please?

Comment: No, you should fix your own website's issue.This warning would pop up for anyone who visited the site. Furthermore this would leave you open to attacks from -other- websites. Don't mess with that setting unless you know what you're doing.